# Python program taking two integer inputs to find even and odd

Tags: python

Here is the code. When I enter an even number (1st number) say 4 and odd number (2nd number) say 5 it prints '4 and 5 are even'

```
num_1=int(input('first number ')) 
num_2=int(input('second number ')) 

if num_1%2==0 & num_2%2==0:
    print(num_1,'and',num_2,'are even')

elif num_1%2!=0 & num_2%2!=0:
    print(num_1,'and',num_2,'are odd')

elif num_1%2!=0 & num_2%2==0:
    print(num_1,'is odd and ',num_2,'is even')

elif num_1%2==0 & num_2%2!=0:
    print(num_1,'is even',num_2,'is odd')

else:
    print('invalid entry')
```

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow!  You may want to have a look at how to best ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  as it stands now, you haven't actually asked a question :)

Comment: `&` is a binary operator that works with bits. You should be using `and` instead.

Comment: the output does not make sense. it mixes up even and odd

Comment: thanks it worked. but why did 'and' work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close! The & operator in python is not the same as 'and' in python. 'and' tests that both conditions are logically true, while '&' is a bitwise operator that can satisfy conditions of logical trues, falses, and integers because these can be combined in bitwise, when 'and' just delineates logic.

```
num_1=int(input('first number '))
num_2=int(input('second number '))

if num_1%2==0 and num_2%2==0:
    print(num_1,'and',num_2,'are even')

elif num_1%2!=0 and num_2%2!=0:
    print(num_1,'and',num_2,'are odd')

elif num_1%2!=0 and num_2%2==0:
    print(num_1,'is odd and ',num_2,'is even')

elif num_1%2==0 and num_2%2!=0:
    print(num_1,'is even',num_2,'is odd')

else:
    print('invalid entry')
```

Answer (score 1):

You've used the wrong operator: you used bit-wise "and" in place of logical "and".  Bit-wise "and" has higher precedence, so your if statement is organized something like this:

```
if (num_1 % 2) == ((0 & num_2) % 2) == 0:
```

Change the `&` items to the logical operator `and`.

Comment: As a new contributor, I think it's kind of a bit hard to interpret your answer.  Though your answer is great, I think writing the simpler solution and followed by this solution would be great to understand.

Answer (score 0):

`&` is a bitwise operator while what you need is a logical operator `and` the equivalent of `&&` in Python