# How to use != sign correctly in if/else clause?

Tags: python, comparison, equality, boolean-logic

Problem: I'm trying to invoke ask_user() again if the user inputs words != 'encrypt' or 'decrypt', but the same error message appears when the input IS correct.

```
def ask_user():
    while True:
        mode = input("Would you like to encrypt or decrypt:   ")
        if mode != 'encrypt' or mode != 'decrypt':          
            print("Please retry; you must type lowercase. \n")
            ask_user()

        else:
            message = input("Enter your message:   ")
```

It seems that using more than one != statements on same line doesn't work as I'd imagined:

```
# test to support above observ.
for n in range(4):
    if n != 2 or n != 3:
        print('me')
    else:
        print(n)
```

How should I change the code to fix this problem?

Comment: `mode not in ('encrypt', 'decrypt')`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: the problem is, if `n` is actually provided the value 2, the `n!=3` becomes true! and if `n` is provided value 3, `n!=2` becomes true! it is impossible to make the two conditions result in a false together! (tl;dr with negation, you really need to think of how the conditionals behave with `or`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have multiple conditions for one if statement in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757965/how-to-have-multiple-conditions-for-one-if-statement-in-python)

Comment: Okay, seriously, do we have a duplicate for these kinds of questions?

Comment: @tripleee I don't think that answers the question. The OP is clearly confused about boolean logic; they're not *really* asking how to implement multiple conditions.

Comment: @Aran-Fey There's gotta be one somewhere. This is a common question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838238/comparing-a-string-to-multiple-items-in-python

Comment: @ tripleee oh come on, I'm not asking for an "efficient" solution involving for loops - which does not seem v efficient to me here...

Comment: [Python program taking two integer inputs to find even and odd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063802/python-program-taking-two-integer-inputs-to-find-even-and-odd/52064012#52064012) is similar, but I wouldn't call it a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `or` instead of `and`.
If you think about how the code is interpreted:

Let's say that `mode="encrypt"`. Step by step:

`mode != 'encrypt'` evaluates to `false`. All good so far.

`mode != 'decrypt'`, however, evaluates to `true`. This is a problem.

The final expression sent to the `if` will be: `false or true`. This, finally, evaluates to `true`, causing the `if` block to be entered.

Changing it to `and` means that both of invalid modes will have to be checked `true` for the block to be entered.

Comment: Thank-you that explains a lot to me @pydude

Answer (score 2):

`n != 2 or n != 3`  will always be true. If `n` is `2` then it's not `3`.  All other values are not `2`.

You intended `n != 2 and n != 3`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `and`, not `or`. Because `n` will never be equal to both 3 and 4, the `if` statement that incorporates `or` will always resolve to `True`